# Прошу помочь разобраться с ошибкой проблема пакета Telebot

Tags: python

база `pyinstaller bot.ру-F`

прога работает

если запускать из IDE Pycharm. Начинаешь ее собирать в `pyinstaller bot.ру-F`, она выдает в командной строе ошибку:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from 'telebot' [11064] Failed to execute script bot ....не буду весь путь писать:_MEI6332\telebot_*init*_.рус)

и

> ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from 'telebot' [10432] Failed to execute script bot

не может импортировать почему то библиотеку

Comment: pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: А потом from telebot import types